# Posting using httppost not being received at server end

Tags: php, android, http-post, httpclient

I am new to Android programming, but have decent knowledge of PHP.

I am trying to send data to my server via post request. I have the following code:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inps = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inps));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
inps.close();
result=sb.toString();
Log.v("data-received",result);
```

I have found the code at numerous places all over the Internet.

On the PHP side I am writing this:

```
<?php
    echo "something".$_REQUEST['year'];
?>
```

But I am only getting "something" (in the Log value "data-received") as the output at my app end?

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to set any environment variable, etc.?

Comment: What is the content-type set to? Needs to be specific for PHP to acknowledge.

Comment: I added content-type too..still not working...

Comment: Make sure your content-type is set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and that your content-length is set as well. I don't know the Java API well enough to say if it's being set for you. In your server side script, do this: "print_r( $_SERVER ); print_r( $_POST );". That will dump the headers and post data to the screen so you can visually inspect the results. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: Hey man, are you the Shubham who did the gem thing for DH4? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. The only change is in the first line:

```
List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePairs>();
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

Does anybody have any idea why is it working?

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` is not always supported, use `$_GET` or `$_POST` depending on where your parameter lives.

Comment: Can you log the request you're _sending_? Maybe you've made a mistake in constructing the request.

Comment: I also tried print_r(var_dump($_REQUEST)), print_r(var_dump($_POST)) and print_r(var_dump($_GET))....its returns array(0){}

Comment: the data I am sending is the first 2 lines...do I need to send anything else along with it?

Comment: I mean, show the _raw_ HTTP request, if you can. If the HTTP request is good then the problem is with the receiver. If the HTTP request is bad the problem with the sender.

Comment: `httppost.getRequestLine()`? I'm guessing here. Also, maybe you should use `setParams()` instead of `setEntity`? http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html

Answer (score 0):

I use this peace of code to send date to a php file. This is using POST. I'm hoping you can do something with it...

```
URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL("url.nl/phppage.php");


              InputStream myInputStream =null;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        //adding some data to send along with the request to the server

    // Data below:  
    sb.append("email="+email.getText().toString()+"&name="+name.getText().toString()+"&message="+om.getText().toString());


                    //url = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn
                            .getOutputStream());
                                // this is were we're adding post data to the request
                                wr.write(sb.toString());
                    wr.flush();
                    myInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                    wr.close();
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                     Log.i("TAG", "Message send successful");
                CharSequence text = "Message send successful";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show(); 
                finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                      Context context = getApplicationContext();
                      Log.e("TAG", "Message not sended - SERVER POST ERROR");
                            CharSequence text = "Message couldn't be send.";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                            toast.show(); 


                }
```

Comment: what is getApplicationContext()?

Comment: @Shubham It's just an function to get a application context. It's sometime given in a function, but this is a workaround if it is not...

Comment: I tried this code...its still not working...is something wrong with the server?

Comment: Are you trying it in the Emulator? Because I remember I had problems with that too.

Answer (score 0):

In the code is already an check, he is giving a toast message and a log when successful. On the php server you can use `print_r($_POST);` This should be no problem. What is the code you're using right now?

Comment: I tried that...gave me an empty array...please check the solution...can you explain why it is happening?

Comment: What is the code you're using right now? Because the posted code is working for me. Isn't the problem with the data you're sending?